# Открытие нескольких окон PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

**У меня есть код:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from info import Ui_Info
from timer15 import Ui_Timer15
from timer4 import Ui_Timer4
from timer10 import Ui_Timer10
import sys

class Ui_Main(object):
    def openInfo(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Info()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

def openTimer_15(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Timer15()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()

def openTimer_4(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Timer4()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()

def openTimer_10(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Timer10()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()

def setupUi(self, Main):
    Main.setObjectName("Main")
    Main.resize(211, 171)
    Main.setStyleSheet("")
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Main)
    self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openTimer_15())
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 171, 31))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openTimer_4())
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 171, 31))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openTimer_10())
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 171, 31))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked = lambda: self.openInfo())
    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 171, 31))
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
    Main.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

При нажатии на любую из кнопок открывается новое окно, **но закрывается предыдущее**, я хочу сделать чтобы новое окно открывалось, но прошлое не закрывалось

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1. `НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ` код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, `НИКОГДА`. Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения. 2. Если вам действительно нужна помощь, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.